# Ability to make suggested tag edits seems to be disabled

Tags: support, review-audits, documentation, moderation

### Background

The creator of this meta question **recently made suggested edits** to some tags on Stackoverflow.

The suggested edits consisted of **creating links to the new SO Documentation feature** where such links did not already exist, and where appropriate.

At the time of this writing, it appears the ability to make suggested **tag edits has been either disabled or is no longer working** (the big blue Edit button no longer displays).

### Examples

Examples of suggested tag edits follows:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13096554
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13096587
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13096613

### Question

Can any more information be provided as to why the ability to make suggested tag edits would be disabled, terminated, or otherwise made inoperable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can only have 5 pending *suggested* edits at any one time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202). Right now, you have 4; I'd guess at the time you asked this, there were 5 still waiting for review.

As more of them are reviewed, you'll be able to make more edits. This prevents any one person from monopolizing the folks reviewing suggested edits.

Note that reviewing these edits requires [reputation >= 5000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), so they can take a little bit longer to be processed than normal edits.