# No error message is shown in the review queue when suggesting an edit is not possible

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits, error-message

I was reviewing first posts, and making a ton of edits (lots of minor formatting fails) when suddenly the edit button stopped working.

This was briefly puzzling, but trying to edit a random question out of the queue quickly cleared up the confusion, as I got a "too many pending edits" message.

This makes total sense, but that error should display inside the review queue as well. Is this an oversight or was something broken on my end?

Comment: Related: [In review mode we have no alert when we try to edit a pending review question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354003); dupe on MSE: [Editing a post during review doesn't show an 'edit not possible' message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797). Seems the error message related to any "suggest edit" is disabled on review queue.

Comment: @StephenRauch No, the other question is totally different and the answer just mentions that you only can have 5 pending suggested edits at a time, which the OP seems to know already. This is a cross-site duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/349538), but I can't find any duplicate on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797

Comment: @Anthon Yes, it's a cross-site duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of [the question it's closed as a duplicate as](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329092/4284627). According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/349538), cross-site duplicates should be left open, and not closed as duplicates of questions that aren't duplicates.

Comment: I have to say, this is most certainly a dup of the above linked MSE question, but **not** a duplicate of the question that it is marked as a duplicate of. In that question the asker wants to know why the edit function is disabled *for tag edits*. (I did not know about the MSE question, as I never visit there)

Comment: The same thing happens when you aren't able to edit due to: `"Another edit is awaiting approval for this post..."`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In review mode we have no alert when we try to edit a pending review question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354003/in-review-mode-we-have-no-alert-when-we-try-to-edit-a-pending-review-question)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but it is the same basic issue...

Answer (score 6):

Starting with the next build, we'll be showing an error message same way as we do on regular question pages:

> [image]

Comment: Are there any news regarding this? I had a same problem today. I've edited the question, wanted to save it and then got a warning that there is a pending review.

Comment: @Dino Which post? Was this in /review? It's possible that while you were making your edit, someone else submitted a suggested edit.

Comment: When in /review there is still no error message saying there are too many edits pending