# No notice when clicking "edit" for a post that already has a pending edit when in a review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I was reviewing the First Posts queue on stackoverflow.com, and one post I came across was not only poorly formatted, but was also in my opinion a poor question (My code isn't working, here's my entire document with no indication of what I've tried).

So I flagged it, and then hit edit as I was going to tidy up the formatting, and I just got sent to the top of the page with no message. Upon clicking through to the actual question to hit edit, I got the "This post already has a pending edit" error.

<sub>Question referenced: [bootstrap modal popup does not show at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467983/bootstrap-modal-popup-does-not-show-at-all)</sub>

Comment: This has already been reported on Meta Stack Exchange several times ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/349538), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299644/349538), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301083/349538), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298927/349538), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300033/349538), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299319/349538), etc). I really wish they would fix this bug.

Comment: @DonaldDuck All 6 of those links point to the same place for me

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356056/no-error-message-is-shown-in-the-review-queue-when-suggesting-an-edit-is-not-pos

Comment: @Scoots They shouldn't point to the same place. They were all marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/349538), but they're different questions.

Comment: They point to the same place because, for anonymous users, duplicate questions redirect to the master question. Donald Duck is logged in to Meta Stack Exchange, so they don't redirect for him.